# jquery ui droppable doesn't do anything

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

I can't seem to get my droppable working.
When I take my .item and move it over to the .itembox it doesn't trigger anything, tho I don't do anything wrong (I guess).
It's an assignment for school and I need to get it fixed by the morning. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(".item").draggable();
$(".itembox").droppable({
    tolerance: "touch",
    drop: function() {
        console.log("hello");
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you able to add your HTML (or a relevant snippet) for reference?

Comment: The code should work assuming you've got jquery loaded and you're using the correct selectors. Here is the jquery documentation that covers these widgets: http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#default

Comment: [Working here](http://jsfiddle.net/UN46u/2/).

Comment: @Phil.Wheeler: please read the homework tag wiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add

```
 accept: 'div.item',
 drop: dropfunction
```

, to your droppable  where dropfunction is somekind of function to be triggered on drop

I'm working on a little [game](http://jsbin.com/unanuf/31/edit) where i'm using drag and drop, you can take a look at my `handleTileDrop` function for more details

I hope this helps, good luck with your project :)